# Exception during secure communication implementation

Tags: wcf

im trying to implement simple secured client server communiction using WCF.
when im launching mt server everty thing is OK , But when im launching my client im getting this error:
Error : An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:800
0/ExchangeService. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is
not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caus
ed by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

**this is the server code :**

```
        Uri address    = new Uri("https://localhost:8000/ExchangeService");

        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();

        //Set Binding Params
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =     HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;


        Type        contract = typeof(ExchangeService.ServiceContract.ITradeService);
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TradeService)); 


        host.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, address);
        host.Open();
```

**this is the client configuration (app.config):**

```
</client>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TradeWsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                   proxyCredentialType ="None"/>
      </security>

    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

the security configuration at both the client and the server are the same , **and i dont need certificate for the server** in that kind of security (transport) so why do i get
this exception ????

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looking at your code:

```
Uri address    = new Uri("https://localhost:8000/ExchangeService");
```

You're specifying that the address is using SSL (https) so it would require a certificate for that purpose. Either use a http binding or install a certificate.

I'd check out the Application Scenarios and How Tos section on this [CodePlex Link](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/) for different configurations and details of how to configure them.